# How can I output all GLM linear predictor terms by row?

Tags: r, glm

I want to output all terms of the linear predictor from a GLM. The number of rows needs to be the same as the original data, and the number of columns needs to match the number of terms of the GLM.

Using predict where type = terms produces the right shape output, but the results don't match the coefficients * factor level. This is because the predict function subtracts of column means.

```
data <- data.frame(var1 = rep(c("a","b","c"),4), var2 = rep(c("d","e"),6), var3 = 1:12)
model <- glm(var3 ~ var1*var2, data = data)
predict(model, data, type = "terms")
```

Going back to the model matrix and multiplying out by the coefficients produces the right results, but the shape of the data is not what I'm after - i.e. the column names also have the levels of the factors, but I just want 3 columns: var1, var2 and var1:var2.

```
coeffs <- coefficients(model)
mm <- model.matrix(model)
t(coeffs * t(mm))
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Potentially:

- a predict function in another package that produces the correct results
- or a simple way to collapse the columns from the model.matrix approach to match the terms of the glm?

Cheers

Comment: At a glance I don't see an option other than replicating the parts of `stats::predict.lm` that you need ...